# Building games through PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, nui

I am new to the whole PhoneGap (among other solutions like Trigger.io). I am interested in making games, and NUI interfaces with these softwares, but I don't know where to start. Does anyone have experience making such products with PhoneGap or the like, and if so, how was it done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a HTML5/JavaScript game as you normally would and then wrap it with PhoneGap.

The use of frameworks such as [Impact](http://impactjs.com/) or [CocoonJS](http://ludei.com/tech/cocoonjs) can help with the first part.